# In multi processing, how can the child processes access the global variable from the parent process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

# list with global scope
result = [100,200]

def square_list(mylist):
    """
    function to square a given list
    """
    global result
    # append squares of mylist to global list result
    for num in mylist:
        result.append(num * num)
    # print global list result
    print("Result(in process p1): {}".format(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # input list
    mylist = [1,2,3,4]

    # creating new process
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=square_list, args=(mylist,))
    # starting process
    p1.start()
    # wait until process is finished
    p1.join()

    # print global result list
    print("Result(in main program): {}".format(result))
```

Here, the global variable `result` can be accessed by the function that is running in a new process. Since the new process has its own python interpreter and its own memory space, how can it access the global variable from the parent process?

Note: I understand about concept of queue/pipe/manager/array/value. This question is specifically to ask how does child process have READ access to global variable from parent process?

Comment: Create a *managed list* instance with: `from multiprocessing import Manager; mylist = Manager().list()` This does *not* use shared memory. See class `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager`, which is returned by the call to `Manager()`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, you should use a *managed list* that is passed as an additional argument to `square_list`:

```python
import multiprocessing

def square_list(result, mylist):
    """
    function to square a given list
    """
    # append squares of mylist to global list result
    for num in mylist:
        result.append(num * num)
    # print global list result
    print("Result(in process p1): {}".format(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # input list
    mylist = [1,2,3,4]

    result = multiprocessing.Manager().list([100,200])

    # creating new process
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=square_list, args=(result, mylist))
    # starting process
    p1.start()
    # wait until process is finished
    p1.join()

    # print global result list
    print("Result(in main program): {}".format(result))
```

Prints:

```
Result(in process p1): [100, 200, 1, 4, 9, 16]
Result(in main program): [100, 200, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

**Notes**

If your subprocess ("child process") were only reading the `result` list, then your code would be fine as is. But things get a bit complicated when you want to update the list and have it reflected back to the main process.

There are two ways a subprocess can update an object that has been created by a main process (I will ultimately get to the issue of the object actually being a *global* variable):

1. The object can be allocated in shared memory so that both processes are actually accessing the same storage although in general they "live" in separate address spaces.
2. The object is a "managed" object represented by a reference to a proxy through which all access is made. When an update to the object is made via the proxy, data is actually being transferred from one address space to another using either sockets or named pipes depending on the platform and other considerations. Thus this is more akin to a remote procedure call.

Let's take the case of a simple shared memory object being updated using a global variable. For this I will use a simple `multiprocessing.Value` instance to create a shared integer:

```python
import multiprocessing

v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1) # initialize to 1

def worker():
    v.value += 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(v.value)
```

On Windows, this prints as `1` and not `11` as you might expect. This is because on Windows new processes are created using the `spawn` method. This means a new, empty address space is created, a new Python interpreter is launched and the source is re-executed from the top and any code at global scope is executed except code within the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block since in the newly minted process `__name__` will not be `"__main__"` (and that is a good thing else otherwise you would get into a recursive loop re-creating new subprocesses).

But this means that the subprocess has just created *its own instance of global variable `v`*. So for this to work, `v` cannot be global and must be passed as an argument to `worker`.

But, there is a way if instead you use a multiprocessing pool. This facility allows you to initialize each process in the pool with a special pool-initializer function:

```python
import multiprocessing

# initialize each process (there is only 1) in the pool
def init_pool(shared_v):
    global v
    v = shared_v # v is global

def worker():
    v.value += 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1) # I am global

    # create pool of size 1:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(v,))
    pool.apply(worker)
```

Prints:

```
11
```

Unfortunately, it is a bit of work to implement a list using the shared-memory data types available. That is why I recommended using a managed list:

```python
import multiprocessing

# initialize each process (there is only 1) in the pool
def init_pool(shared_result):
    global result
    result = shared_result # result is global

def square_list(mylist):
    """
    function to square a given list
    """
    # append squares of mylist to global list result
    for num in mylist:
        result.append(num * num)
    # print global list result
    print("Result(in process p1): {}".format(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # input list
    mylist = [1,2,3,4]

    result = multiprocessing.Manager().list([100,200])

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(result,))
    pool.apply(square_list, args=(mylist,))

    # print global result list
    print("Result(in main program): {}".format(result))
```

```
Result(in process p1): [100, 200, 1, 4, 9, 16]
Result(in main program): [100, 200, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

**This technique works in Windows, Linux, etc., i.e. all platforms.**

Move your updatable global variables to within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block (they are still global to the main process) and use a pool-initializer function to initialize the pool processes with these variables. In fact, for platforms that use `spawn`, you should consider moving all global definitions that are not required by subprocesses and are expensive to create to within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: I understand about concept of queue/pipe/manager/array/value. This question is specifically to ask how does child process have access to global variable from parent process?

Comment: I will update the answer and explain this better. You will just have to give me a few minutes -- I am tied up with something at the moment.

Comment: See the added **Notes**. The last code example is, I believe, the best you can do in this situation where you are trying to update the object created by the parent.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. I reiterate that I am not asking how to update the global list from child process. I want to know exactly how is the child process (that spins up its own python interpreter and has its own memory space) has access to READ the global variable from the parent process?

Comment: I answered that.  In your code it is not reading **the same global variable that was created by the main process**. It is initializing its own global variable named `result` in its own address space. I don't know how to say this any more clearly. On Linux/Unix, it is a different story. By the way, when you tag a question with `multiprocessing`, you are requested to also tag the question with your platform. I am inferring that you are running on a platform that uses `spawn` to create new processes.

Comment: In your answer you are giving examples of Value object. Where as my question is having a simple variable. I want to know that - since both are separate processes, then how does python allow child process to access global variable (a simple variable containing list as shown in my quesiton) of parent process.

Comment: 1. See my examples of using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments with the `Pool` constructor. 2. Then read up on the various [shared memory types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=array#shared-ctypes-objects) that are available and read up on the [SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=syncmanager#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) to see what *managed* objects (using proxies) are available. Those are your choices. There are no "lists" in the former; you would have to implement your own list using these.

Comment: And I have already said that if all you want to do is read a list, then the code you have written, that is, having `result = [100,200]` at global scope is OK. That was the first sentence of my **Notes**.

Comment: Exactly and my question is, since both are separate processes with their own memory space, then how (technically how does this work) does python allow the child process to READ the global from parent process memory space?

Comment: I have answered this multiple times already. Pretend now *your life* depended on *you* telling *me* the answer. Re-read *everything carefully including the comments*. The answer is there. Hint: The child process does *not* read the global from the parent process memory space. It is re-creating an instance of the global in its own address space. Oops. I went ahead and accidentally answered your question again (for the last time).

Answer (score 0):

One of the key tenants of processes vs threads is that they don't share memory. There are a few things that exist to *actually* share memory, but in general with processes, you should pass messages via queues, pipes, etc..

Here is an example of passing a return value back to the parent via a queue:

```py
import multiprocessing

# list with global scope
result = [100,200] #result is re-created on import here in the child process

def square_list(mylist, ret_q):
    """
    function to square a given list
    """
    global result 
    # append squares of mylist to global list result
    for num in mylist:
        result.append(num * num)
    # print global list result
    print("Result(in process p1): {}".format(result))
    ret_q.put(result) #send the modified result to the main process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # input list
    mylist = [1,2,3,4]

    #return queue
    ret_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # creating new process
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=square_list, args=(mylist, ret_q))
    # starting process
    p1.start()
    # wait for the result
    result = ret_q.get()
    # wait until process is finished
    p1.join()

    # print global result list
    print("Result(in main program): {}".format(result))
```

Comment: What if the OP were  simplifying the problem but really had *two* lists of numbers to be squared and appended to `result` and is creating *two* `Process` instances  giving to each one a list to work on? Each process would see the same initial value of `result` and this would not work at all. You gave a great answer to "How do I return a value back from a `Process`?", but that really wasn't the question. Both processes must share the same list instance if it is going to solve the problem by updating the list instead of returning the new values for the main process to do the appending. (...More)

Comment: @Booboo imao, passing messages is much less likely to get messy than shared state. the example was simply a minimal change to the existing code to return the value.

Comment: But even with just one list and one process, the question was how could the child process update the list and you came up with a way that solve the problem but not really answer the original question.

Comment: @Booboo the answer to "how to access globals in the parent" is you can't because memory isn't shared... you always need message passing or a proxy. I demonstrated message passing (which I believe to generally be cleaner than proxies to shared state).

Comment: My point is that if you instead had `square_list` return just the 4 values it computed and then had the main process append those results to `result`, it would work even in my multiple processes case.

Comment: I think that's falling into the territory of "it's up to the OP to decide how to implement"... The only point I'm trying to get across is how to send something from a child to the parent. To me, using message passing is cleaner because it's more explicit than using a proxy (re `import this`). It is very explicit what my example does, and it should be fairly easy to customize how OP wants it to work. Proxies aren't a bad solution, they're just not what I prefer. I think having both solutions demonstrated is a good thing

Comment: I understand about concept of queue/pipe/manager/array/value. This question is specifically to ask how does child process have access to global variable from parent process?